# Find k-shortest path in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

I'm using  GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(PathExpander expander,int maxDepth,int maxHitCount)  to find the k-shortest path, but the problem, I don't get direct path between two nodes. For example, I have relationship like

```
n1--n2
n1--n3
n3--n2
```

If I try to find the path between n1 and n2 I get only single path as n1--n3--n2, but actually, there are two paths one of which is a direct path from n1 to n2.

```
CustomPathExpander expander = toExpander(constraints, db, Collections.<FakeNode>emptyList());

List<Path> result = new LinkedList<Path>();
for (Path path : GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander, 3, 3).findAllPaths(n1, n2)) 
{
result.add(path);
}


static CustomPathExpander toExpander(String constraints, FakeGraphDatabase db, Iterable<FakeNode> extraNodes) {
    return toExpander(toMap(constraints), db, extraNodes);
}


static CustomPathExpander toExpander(Map<String,Object> c, FakeGraphDatabase db, Iterable<FakeNode> extraNodes) {
    Map<String,String> directions = (Map<String, String>) (c == null ? null : c.get("dir"));
    Map<String,Object> constraints = (Map<String, Object>) (c == null ? null : c.get("c"));
    Map<String,Object> inline = (Map<String,Object>)(c == null ? null : c.get("inline"));

    DirectionContraints d = new DirectionContraints(directions);
    IPathConstraint path = PathConstraints.parse(constraints);
    InlineRelationships rel = InlineRelationships.of(inline, db);

    return new CustomPathExpander(d, path, rel, extraNodes, c != null && c.get("acyclic") == Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: can you paste the java code used so we can better help you

Comment: Added the code snippet